# Is it possible to connect a single Dropbox Mac app with two or more Dropbox accounts?

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to connect a single Dropbox Mac app with two or more Dropbox accounts?

Assume I have corporate and private account. How can I use a single dropbox app for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it out of one copy of the app, but it seems that you can duplicate the app. You can see (somewhat complicated) instructions here:

http://maketecheasier.com/run-multiple-dropbox-accounts-in-mac-and-linux/2010/05/24

I haven't done this personally, but this looks like it should work.

Comment: It is a somewhat complicated process. Multiple simultaneous different dropbox accounts is a [feature very well requested](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/118/multiple-accounts) that must come along eventually. So second option is waiting.

Comment: I seriously doubt it will ever happen. Dropbox makes their revenue from selling upgraded accounts with more storage. If they started letting people have multiple free accounts, their revenue will drop.

Comment: what if the multiple account feature isn't free? Anyway, there must be a model that works.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with one copy of Dropbox. For my secondary account, I run an automator script on login that sets:

`HOME=$HOME/Desktop/SECONDARY-DROPBOX /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox &`

I end up with two dropbox icons in the menu bar. I configure one to be alternate black/white icon so I can distinguish visibly between the two.

Answer (score 0):

My (less complicated?) fix to this was...

I have two Mac accounts:

Robert, Corp a/c
Bob, Personal a/c

Dropbox installed on both Accounts synching to

```
/Volumes/Working/Websync/Robert/Dropbox
/Volumes/Working/Websync/Bob/Dropbox
```

From a Terminal window in the Bob account

```
bob$>su Robert -c /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox
```

You'll be prompted for password for Robert

Dropbox will run something like

```
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python27.zip
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
```

Open a new terminal shell 'Cmd-T' and then run Dropbox for Bob

```
bob$> /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox
```

I'm running Dropbox v2.8.2 on Mountain Lion

Thanks to [Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237/mark) for his answer to this [Can I start an application as another user without actually switching users?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25907/can-i-start-an-application-as-another-user-without-actually-switching-users)

[Image: Two Dropbox Accounts running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLJfe.png)

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do that using multiple OS X accounts, running the same copy of Dropbox in each of them.