# Can I start an application as another user without actually switching users?

Tags: macos, applications, user-account

Is there a way to start an application as another user so that the started application would use the other user's preferences/history/resources et al?

For example: I've logged in as Alice and I'd like to start Firefox as Bob, so therefore Firefox would show Bob's browsing history instead of Alice's.

I tried

```
$ su Bob
$ open -a Firefox
```

But with no apparent effect; as a matter of a fact Activity monitor shows the Firefox process is being run by Alice—not Bob.

I understand I will need Bob's login credentials, but that's not a problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the command line **you have to find the Unix executable** and run it using [sudo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) like so:

```
$ sudo -u Bob /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/Firefox
```

… or the same with su: (however this also needs you to set up a password for root - which I do not recommend)

```
$ su Bob
$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/Firefox
```

(…or the above in one line:)

```
$ su Bob -c /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/Firefox
```

---

In the past, the easiest way for PPC Macs was to use [Pseudo](http://homepage.mac.com/brianhill/pseudo.html), but it has been long [discontinued](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5620/pseudo). This is to drop the application icon on Pseudo's icon or window.

Comment: Ah, the key was to find the Unix executable. It works also with `su` if one wishes not to `sudo`. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, when trying to run Google Chrome I get this: `Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Comment: When using the `sudo` approach I get login failures even though I use the correct password for the other user. `su` works on the other hand (no password for root set)

Comment: @lapplandscohan sudo takes the password of the current user

Comment: Amazing. Truly Amazing. _Note that macOS will not allow sharing of the clipboard_ between the application running as another user, and the primary user.

Comment: @evan.bovie YTes shows they have thought of security

Answer (score 4):

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102105/1860 for why `su` does not work for all applications.

### launchd's bsexec

Recent versions of `launchd` have the ability the launch applications within another user's session; although Apple engineers have not recommended its general use.

Use the `bsexec` option in [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) to target the appropriate user session:

```
 bslist [PID | ..] [-j]
          This prints out Mach bootstrap services and their respective states. While the namespace
          appears flat, it is in fact hierarchical, thus allowing for certain services to be only avail-
          able to a subset of processes. The three states a service can be in are active ("A"), inactive
          ("I") and on-demand ("D").

          If [PID] is specified, print the Mach bootstrap services available to that PID. If [..] is
          specified, print the Mach bootstrap services available in the parent of the current bootstrap.
          Note that in Mac OS X v10.6, the per-user Mach bootstrap namespace is flat, so you will only
          see a different set of services in a per-user bootstrap if you are in an explicitly-created
          bootstrap subset.

          If [-j] is specified, each service name will be followed by the name of the job which regis-
          tered it.

 bsexec PID command [args]
          This executes the given command in the same Mach bootstrap namespace hierachy as the given
          PID.

 bstree [-j]
          This prints a hierarchical view of the entire Mach bootstrap tree. If [-j] is specified, each
          service name will be followed by the name of the job which registered it.  Requires root priv-
          ileges.
```

The recommended approach is to write a launchd job ticket and restart the Mac - or ask the user to log-out and back in again.

Answer (score 1):

One more method:

```
# chown someuser command
# chmod u+s command
$ ./command
```

Thanks to wysota at : 
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4730-Linux-Bash-Run-a-command-as-another-user

(Spent a lot of time hunting for something that works in my particular situation, figured I'd spread the wealth)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ssh. I.e. `ssh username@123.456.00`. As you said, you'll need the password for the user. Then you can do what you're asking. You'll need to enable remote login under System Prefs>Sharing:
[image: Remote Login Preference]
Then, you can just do `open -a Firefox` and Firefox will open as the other user, not yours.

Comment: Unfortunately I get: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Firefox.app with error -10810.` when trying `open -a Firefox` :-|

Comment: @koiyu Try `sudo open -na Firefox`

Comment: it fails as above :-/ (also using the path to the unix executable fails, albeit differently.)

Comment: @koiyu Permissions? What does `ls -l` say for Firefox?

Comment: Processes started from an SSH session do not have access to the GUI. If this works on your system I suspect you changed some low-level configuration at some point.

Comment: So this wouldn't work in *my* case; but for someone who doesn't need app's GUI, this might be a feasible alternative :-)

Comment: @koiyu: The `sudo` option mentioned in the other answer (with the path to the executable) works at least under Lion.

Comment: @patrix, yes, that is because it doesn't use SSH. (Also, because it works, I had accepted the answer.)

Comment: @Tobias Nope. Didn't change a thing. Just SSHed in then `open -a <application>` and it opens the application's GUI.

Comment: @daviesgeek but did you SSH into a user other than the one who currently has the GUI, as the OP wanted.