# Run app as a different user (automator)

Tags: terminal, automator, user-account

i'd like to be able to open an app as a different user.
For example PC1 is my main account and PC7 is my secondary one.

I can achieve the effect in terminal using

su - pc7 
*insert password*
/Applications/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName

How can i use the automator to make a script/app whatever that does this by a simple doubleclick?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not trivially launch graphical applications as another user.

### A Proxy Process is Required

To launch a graphical application as another user, that user must be logged in to a graphical session and have a process running within their session able to launch your desired application.

Prior to OS X 10.9, this could be approximated via the `launchctl` command. See [How to launch a GUI application in another user's graphical session?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102105/1860) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: This is not completely true, if you are user A you can launch a graphical application as user B within the graphical session where A has logged in...

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 be aware that doing this can result in the user B application running within the graphical session of user A – and thus sharing a common WindowServer session. Depending on the frameworks and services the application uses, this can lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save your example as a text file adding the suffix .command or .sh to it to execute it with a double-click. AppleScript can call an .sh-script, too, with

```
do shell script "/path/to/yourscript.sh"
```

Not sure if Automator can do the same.

But `su` basically only works with commands not using the Aqua GUI of Mac OS X. So if you try to open an application like for example TextEdit this way, it wont be able to open a window on the Desktop.

Comment: `su` works fine with GUI apps…?

Answer (score 0):

If you were were to open AppleScript, you would use the following format:

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/su - " & user & " -c " & "'" & cmd & "'" with administrator privileges password "blahblah"
```

If you wanted to make a shell script, you'd need to `chmod a+x` the file and write it out like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
su -c "/Applications/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName" -s /bin/sh pc7
```

Or, you can write it how I would write it:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
su -c "/Applications/Application.app/Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName" -s /bin/sh pc7
```

---

1. Save the file as `YourScritpt.sh`
2. Add executable permissions by typing `chmod a+x YourScript.sh` in Terminal
3. Right-click the file in Finder and select 'Open with" and select "Other"
4. Select Terminal as the application to open the file (change to All Applications)
5. You do not need to select "Always Open With"