# How to launch Google Drive in another user's session?

Tags: macos, user-account, google-apps

This is basically a follow up of a [very similar broader question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100829/how-to-launch-a-gui-application-in-another-users-graphical-session).

Say I have two users, **foo** and **bar**. Only **foo** is logged in. If I manually log **bar** in I could set up Google Drive to auto start under *System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items*. In fact, it's probably already set up there, and this is what I currently do to achieve what I want: have 2 google drive sessions running simultaneously on my machine.

But, without this, how could I launch it without switching users from **foo**? And would it be possible to launch it even without logging in **bar**? If not, how could I automate logging in **foo** and **bar** after reboot? I'm just looking for ways to automate this process (of having to login another user) and keep Drive working even after eventual random failures.

Now, the similar question does have a very intersting answer suggesting using `launchd's bsexec` and a trampoline-like process on **bar**, which would be quite complicated to achieve even with a script. And it does say "*Apple Engineers do not recommend its general use*", whatever that means.

If it were dropbox, I could be using [dropbox cli](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli). But Drive doesn't have such an option...

Comment: why is it necessary to have simultaneous fobar using Google drive on a single computer ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 think different, huh? I just want to keep my work and home google drive in sync with my personal computer. But I could as well simply want to run 2 simultaneous GUI applications which have some useful background process but no command line version. IMHO, "why is doing such thing so complicated?" would be a much better question.

Comment: I have 2 Google (accounts) drives, and did not think of using them both as same time, but ?? let me try.

Comment: OK, I did it and it works.

Comment: @Buscar웃 what you mean? Using just 1 mac user-account?! I can't connect to a second drive account without disconnecting the first here.

Comment: I used 2 Google Drives at same time on one computer. But i cheated, I used the web version only (with 2 browsers), not the installed versions.

Comment: The GDriveFS project may make this possible: https://github.com/dsoprea/GDriveFS and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306252/google-drive-with-fuse