# Running a script as root and presenting a GUI to logging in users

Tags: macos, script, python

I am having a programming decision problem and hope, that you can show me a solution or tell me, if my plan on how to solve the problem would be okay or not.

I am managing some macs and want to run a script every time a user logs in. The script (which I haven't written yet) needs to make some changes (or not). The changes need administrator privileges but the script also needs information from the currently logged in (or logging in) user.

Normaly, this would be a job for a LaunchAgent / Deamon, but here comes the problem: Scripts in /LaunchDeamons run as system administrator but start together with the system. They are not aware of users loging in or out and they may not show a GUI. ~/LaunchAgents run as the logged in user and get started when the user logs in. Also they may show a GUI. However they do not run as system administrator.

So this is my problem: running a script as root, but starting it whenever a user logs in and present a GUI to him: My solution would be to write two scripts:

Script 1 runs as system administrator and lies in /LaunchDeamons. This would have a Socket open for incomming connections (AKA "Server Socket").

Script 2 runs as the user beeing logged in and lies in ~/LaunchAgents. It presents a GUI to the user and sends the information to script 1 via a socket connection.

It doesn't seem to me as this would be the most reliable / straight forward solution, but I can't think of anything else. I also tried to find out how other programs solve this problem (munki for example, which presents a GUI to the user but installs programs as system administrator) but couldn't figure out how they did it.

I'd be happy for some comments on this! 
Regards, Christian

PS: I plan to use python.

Comment: Are the Macs part of a domain? Will the users authenticate against this domain or locally? If they are domain/network users the solution becomes much more straightforward in the form of a domain admin account running your script.

Comment: If two different users log in to the same Mac what do you want to happen? i.e. chnage will differ per user

Comment: @agentroadkill: well, partially ;). The macs are actually many different users in different companies: some are part of a domain and some are not ;)

Comment: @Mark: Both shall see the GUI and be able to enter information. The information the script installs is not "preemptive". (It is individual per user but needs administrator privileges to install)

Comment: Where is the info stored?

Comment: If you've not tried the answer below, please do and report back. Otherwise there is an interesting [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82397/run-script-as-root-at-login-no-sudoer-user-shell-session) on askUbuntu. Can scripts be run with sudo privileges from a login shell (I believe that's where the scripts you're asking about get run from) on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

## Sockets - Involved but Tried and Tested

Your solution of two scripts talking through a socket is the tried and tested approach. We did this for [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) and it has worked reliably from OS X 10.3 – 10.11.

You can use a tcp or unix domain socket for this purpose.

In our situation, the daemon [`pmd`](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/v4/administrator/pm.tool.pmd.html) runs as a computer wide process and the user session daemon [`pmuser`](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/v4/administrator/pme.agent.pmuser.html) runs once per user. They talk to share information that a computer wide daemon [can not safely obtain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION24) and to perform actions within specific user sessions.

The computer wide daemon can detect when a user logs in. This is done through the SystemConfiguration API `SCDynamicStoreKeyCreateConsoleUser`.

The graphical script must be launched within the graphical user session; a launchd job in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` with the key value pair `LimitLoadToSessionType`: `Aqua` set will ensure this.

Depending on the information you need to gather from the user, I expect what you want to achieve is possible with Power Manager; feel free to [get in touch](https://www.dssw.co.uk/support/).

### launchctl's bsexec

Recent versions of OS X include a `launchctl` that promises what you need: the ability to launch a process within a user session. See [How to launch a GUI application in another user's graphical session?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100829/how-to-launch-a-gui-application-in-another-users-graphical-session) for the details and likely problems you will encounter.

If you are deploying on OS X 10.10 and later, investigate launchd's new domain capabilities. A complete rewrite in OS X 10.10 opened up many as yet not completely documented options. The [launchd mailing list](https://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/launchd-dev) is a treasure trove of information.